# generalized sieve implementations

Tags: nt.number-theory, computer-algebra

Suppose I have a multiplicative function $f$ and I want to compute it for *all* integers from $1$ to $N$ (or maybe just for a long sequence of consecutive integers). It is clear that this is far faster to do with a sieve algorithm than by factoring each one of the arguments. The question is: does any known computer algebra system actually implement this?

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: If computing $f(p^k)$ is $\mathcal{O}(1)$ then the obvious algorithm takes $\mathcal{O}(N \log N)$ operations to compute $f(n), n \in 1\ldots N$. Why would you want something better ?

Comment: The obvious algorithm also computes functions like $\mu(n)$ in time $O(N\log N)$ and space around $\sqrt{N}$ --- by chunking the interval $[1,N]$ into subintervals of length $\sqrt{N}$.   Helfgott has recently considered a refinement of this which reduces the space requirement to about $N^{\frac 13}$.  The downvotes do seem uncalled for.

Comment: @reuns By the "obvious" algorithm do you mean the obvious sieve algorithm? Otherwise, THE obvious algorithm involves factoring each number.

Comment: The obvious algorithm for factoring all the integers $ \le N$ is $\mathcal{O}(\sum_{k \le N} \lfloor N/k \rfloor) = \mathcal{O}( N \log N)$. As is, your question is unclear.

Comment: Now I don't know any CAS capable to work with Dirichlet series in a satisfying way. This is an interesting question. For example, what would be the programming framework required to find the asymptotic of $\sum_{n \le x} \phi(n) n^a$ ? More generally, to manipulate Mellin transforms, explicit formulas, assumptions (abscissa of convergence, zero-free regions, Lindelöf hypothesis..) ? @Lucia

Comment: @reuns What you are describing is a sieve algorithm. The obvious algorithm factors EVERY SINGLE $n\leq N$ as if the others did not exist. This runs in time $O(N^{3/2})$ for the stupid factoring algorithm, and $O(N f(\log(N)))$ for the smart factoring algorithm, where $f$ is a function growing faster than any polynomial. Geez...

Comment: Yes so what is your question ?